# JavaFX Dynamic Form Field UI

Tags: javafx

Does anyone know how to imitate the functionality from the UI components shown below? I want to replicate adding form fields when text is entered into the TextField box. I don't need the dropdown button, just the dynamic adding of the forms.

[image: screenshot of desired UI components]

Comment: let's see, If the two `TextFields` have text. Enable +. Also, add a remove option to down arrow button.  Once + is pressed add two more `TextFields` with `Buttons` below the current structure. If the remove option is selected, remove the current structure.

Comment: Which functionality are you trying to imitate? Showing the UI elements? Change the `enabled` property of the `+` button? Actually apply the styles to another element?  Your question is far too vague to answer.

Comment: I edited my question for you, thanks @Zephyr

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the children of a `GridPane` adding a new `TextField` & `Button` every time one of the buttons is activated. Listen to the `text` properties to enable/disable the `Button` and save the results.

```
private static void insertRow(GridPane grid, List<String> values, int index) {
    // increment index of children with rowIndex >= index
    for (Node n : grid.getChildren()) {
        int row = GridPane.getRowIndex(n);
        if (row >= index) {
            GridPane.setRowIndex(n, row + 1);
        }
    }

    TextField text = new TextField();

    Button add = new Button("+");
    add.setDisable(true);
    add.setOnAction(evt -> {
        insertRow(grid, values, GridPane.getRowIndex(add) + 1);
    });

    values.add(index, "");

    text.textProperty().addListener((a, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        add.setDisable(newValue.isEmpty());
        values.set(GridPane.getRowIndex(add), newValue);
    });

    grid.addRow(index, text, add);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    insertRow(grid, list, 0);
    Button print = new Button("print");
    print.setOnAction(evt -> {
        System.out.println(list);
    });
    grid.add(print, 0, 1);
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll go ahead and try this after the first answer.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for and may not be the best way to do this, but should be easy to adapt it to your needs.

Basically, you will need a list of `HBox` objects to be added to a `VBox` in your application. You could create the list yourself and bind it to the children of your `VBox`, or just add/remove the `HBox`es to/from the `VBox` using the `getChildren().add()` and `getChildren().remove()` methods.

Here is a complete little application to demonstrate the concept. I created an internal class to handle the `HBox` with the fields you need. This could be adapted to be more felixable:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static VBox mainPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        mainPane = new VBox(5);
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        mainPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        mainPane.getChildren().add(new UIForms());

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    static void addField() {
        mainPane.getChildren().add(new UIForms());
    }

    static void removeField(UIForms field) {
        if (mainPane.getChildren().size() > 1) {
            mainPane.getChildren().remove(field);
        }
    }
}

class UIForms extends HBox {

    private TextField textField1;
    private TextField textField2;

    private Button btnAddField;
    private Button btnRemoveField;

    public UIForms() {

        // Setup the HBox layout
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        setSpacing(5);

        // Create the UI controls
        textField1 = new TextField();
        textField2 = new TextField();
        btnAddField = new Button("+");
        btnRemoveField = new Button("-");

        // Setup button actions
        btnAddField.setOnAction(e -> Main.addField());
        btnRemoveField.setOnAction(e -> Main.removeField(this));

        // Add the UI controls
        getChildren().addAll(
                textField1, textField2, btnAddField, btnRemoveField
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll go ahead and try this.

Comment: Why downvote a helpful answer without any explanation as to why?